# Two BR tags between inline images (within wrapper) causing spacing differences in Firefox vs every other browser. Example done in JSfiddle

Tags: html, css, browser

JS Fiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/Xfvpu/1/

Okay so I have a document with xhtml doctype and I use the proper br / tag
but for some reason the gap between two images renders differently in Firefox than it does every other browser.

The page is can be found at http://www.safaviehhome.com/Rugs/Area-Rugs.html

the CSS is all mixed up unfortunately so I can't explicitly post it, but the two images are within a DIV wrapper, and the images themselves are not in seperate divs. They both have image maps, and the size between the two images width only differ by around 20px.

In between the two images are two    br /
tags, I tried fiddling around in Firebug but could not figure it out .. And I won't be happy until I figure this out .. it's pissing me off! :)

The difference between other browsers and Firefox is around a 10px difference .. Firefox adds extra spacing .. I'm not asking for any help specifically, just wanted to see if there is some rendering issues I'm not aware of so I can put this issue to rest.

Look in other browsers vs Firefox to see what I mean .. I would really appreciate some help I need to figure this out for my own knowledge.

Comment: Please someone answer, I provided the example. I hate not knowing things!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rely on using `<br/>` for vertical spacing. You need to use styles, such as

```
<div style="margin-top:5px">image goes here</div>
```

Or even:

```
<img style="margin-top:5px" src="yourimg.jpg" />
```

In my experience browsers are sufficiently consistent if you use this approach.

*Edited to add:*

**But** (and I can't stress this strongly enough): browsers will *never* be entirely consistent. Designs which assume that 100% consistency is possible will **fail**. (If this seems harsh, try getting through one day using only your smartphone's browser. Yuck.)

Comment: Ah I see, thank you sir. I will make the change right now, but can you explain why I can't rely on br  tags?

Comment: Chosen answer cause he came first

Comment: I hear you on the edited bit, its hard for me to accept and I will try EVERYTHING in my power to make it consistent, but your right I will have to settle with inconsistencies unfortunately. It's a fun process regardless, very rewarding when you figure it out ..

Comment: You can't rely on `<br>` tags for vertical spacing, for one thing, because they rely on styles like `font-size` and `line-height` to determine the height of the "blank" line.  It's also not a good design principle; sure, circa-1995 we used this form of vertical spacing, but now we have better methods.

Comment: Gotcha, saluce. Good to know, though I'm new I focus on doing everything semantically correct, and having 100% browser compatibility and a w3c valid document. Seems like that can't always be the case though ..

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know the exact reason why Firefox acts like it does, I can offer an advice. From my experience using br tags for layout are, er, not the wisest idea, since you easily lose control of the exact spacing it creates. Like in this case, where it seems that Firefox intreprets two br tags as two lines, whereas at least Opera take the first one as a line break after the map and the second one creates this empty space.

You didn't ask for a workaround, but I can't resist: [take a look at br-less alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfvpu/8/).

Comment: Hehe thanks for the workaround, glad to see it wasn't my unsemantic mark-up causing the issue. I will make the changes now, but I still find it very strange ..